# How to start or stop IIS-8.5 website on a remote server in different domain

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cross-domain, msdeploy, iis-8.5

I wonder if we can start or stop a website on IIS-8.5 running on a remote server which is on a different domain (I can provide the credentials if needed in batch file).

I know if it is a local site running on our machine we can use batch file like,

```
@echo off
appcmd start sites "local.xyz.com"
pause
```

I appreciate your help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't even think about putting credentials to any machine or domain in a batch file.  Not ever!

Comment: @jwdonahue Then how to address the issue, without credentials, because my websites are on a different domain, I need to deploy the packages on those sites.

Answer (score 1):

Several options. I just list two below,

- If you can use PowerShell remoting, then you can easily access `appcmd` or equivalent commands on the remote machine.
- If you can deploy [IIS Administration API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/getting-started), you get even more possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, after so much of research, I end up using msdeploy, reason is we can skip some folders if it has lock.